# book for study finite element method

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I want to study finite element method for study partial differential equations in particular for parabolic type equation. Can you recommend a book which includes espesially mathematical background?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: advanced engineering mathematics(Kreyszig)

Comment: Relevant: [Any great *introductory* books for Finite (Element/Difference) Methods](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/any-great-introductory-books-for-finite-element-difference-methods).

Answer (score 5):

I came up too late, but I recommend a series of books for finite element method with different approach for future reading.

For engineering approach:

- *Huebner - The Finite Element Method For Engineers.*

For a introduction to the mathematical theory:

- *Sayas - A gentle Introduction to Finite Element Method  [link](https://team-pancho.github.io/documents/anIntro2FEM_2015.pdf).*
- *Brenner & Scott - The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Method.*
- *Braess - Finite Elements Theory, Fast Solvers, and Applications in Elasticity Theory.*
- *Solin et al. - Higher-Order Finite Element Methods.* (Implementation aspects)

Introductory books for research purposes.

- *Demkowicz- Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Method* [link](http://users.oden.utexas.edu/%7Eleszek/classes/EM394H/book.pdf) (For DPG method with optimal test functions).
- *Gatica - A Simple Introduction to the Mixed Finite Element Method.*
- *Sayas - First steps in the boundary element method [link](https://team-pancho.github.io/documents/BEM.pdf)*
- *Girault & Raviart - Finite element methods for Navier-Stokes equations.*
- *Monk - Finite Element Methods for Maxwell's Equations.*

Online Courses:

- [Introduction to Finite Element Methods](https://open.umich.edu/find/open-educational-resources/engineering/introduction-finite-element-methods#lectures)
- [High Performance Finite Element Modeling-i-and-ii-1.769003](https://www.kth.se/en/studies/mooc/high-performance-finite-element-modeling-i-and-ii-1.769003)

Answer (score 1):

Try Larson, Bengzon: *The Finite Element Method.*