# Resource request for Finite Difference Methods .

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, book-recommendation, finite-differences

I am a beginner in Finite Difference Method(FDM),I was looking for some basic introductory resources (text/reference/notes/video lectures) on Finite Difference Methods (it will be good if it  includes both computational and mathematical techniques of different FDM methods).

Searching gave me this link [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252231/review-paper-book-on-finite-difference-methods-for-pdes),[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/any-great-introductory-books-for-finite-element-difference-methods)but that is more kind of devoted to PDE's,ODE's.

Any reference,recommendation is great!.

Thanks!

Comment: Computational Fluid Dynamics, Vol 1 by K A Hoffmann is essentially the solution of pde's using finite difference methods. Lots of schemes are studied in detail and a half decent engineering maths background will suffice to follow it. It would be difficult to find any book on finite difference methods which does not come from PDE's I should think.

Answer (score 1):

Parviz Moin's "Fundamentals of Engineering Numerical Analysis" is a good introductory text. MATLAB codes used in the text are available at http://numerics.stanford.edu/ta/